# How do i move my Minecraft profile to a device with no internet capability?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I'm copying Minecraft over to my other computer (Which for rather inconvenient reasons, is incapable of establishing an internet connection). But after copying it onto the machine from a flash drive, I'd accidentallly logged out from the launcher. Is there some sort of file i could copy over from my internet-capable machine to essentially log me back in?

Comment: Can you not just remember your password? And since you have internet on the one machine, just reset it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to log in on the other computer. Consider buying a small USB wifi adapter and connecting to a network or setup a hotspot on your phone and connect to it.